# Передать в функцию массив значений javascrypt?

Tags: массивы, функции, javascript

С вами снова я! Добрый вечер) вот такой код

```
function allarr (arr) {

for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
alert(arr[i]);

}

}
```

где arr массив со значениями - но почему то функция не хочет работать если без цикла алертнуть значение массива к примеру alert(arr[1]); выдает что оно пустое - запускаю функцию я так -

```
allarr(arr);
```

Comment: а что именно передаете в функцию? то есть, понятно, что вызываете как `allarr(arr)`, но какое значение arr  в этом месте?

Comment: нужен более полный листинг программы

Answer (score 2):

Посмотрите вот здесь есть работающий пример http://jsfiddle.net/pvkovalev/G5m2P/
Исходный данных не много, надеюсь это вам поможет.
Для манипуляции с DOM я использовал jQuery, но это конечно на ваш выбор.

HTML

```
<div id="output"></div>
```

JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var data = new Array("A", "B", "C");
    A(data);
})

function A(arr) {
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        $('#output').append(i + " " + arr[i] + "<br/>");
    }
}
```